# Return Chosen Slicer Values as variant

Tags: vba, pivot-table, variant, slicers

Option Explicit

```
Sub TestExample()
    Dim MyArr() As Variant
    MyArr = ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems("Slicer_A")
    'now variable MyArr keeps all items in an array
End Sub

Public Function ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems(MySlicerName As String) As Variant
    'This function returns an array of the limited set of items in Slicer A
    'Limitation is due to both:
    '(1) direct selection of items by user in slicer A
    '(2) selection of items in slicer B which in consequence limits the number of items in slicer A
    Dim ShortList() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0 'for iterate
    Dim sC As SlicerCache
    Dim sI As SlicerItem 'for iterate
    Set sC = ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(MySlicerName)
    For Each sI In sC.SlicerItems
        If sI.Selected = True And sI.HasData = True Then 'Here is the condition!!!
                'Debug.Print sI.Name
            ReDim Preserve ShortList(i)
            ShortList(i) = sI.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next sI

    ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems = ShortList
End Function
```

Just recently discovered this code, but the line gets an error

```
For Each sI In sC.SlicerItems
```

Could anyone help to figure this out, a variant type stored value is a must for me
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Paul, I would say make sure your *MySlicerName* variable is correct. Try to test by printing `sC.SlicerItems.Count` to see if it's not 0. Also, from the MS Docs site - *Attempting to access the SlicerItems property for slicers that are connected to an external OLAP data source (SlicerCache. OLAP = True) generates a run-time error. *

Hard to say without knowing the actual error.